# Mosquitto not Starting in Docker Container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, mqtt, mosquitto

I am building a Docker container from an Ubuntu image using Dockerfile.  I would like the container to use the mosquitto broker.

In my dockerfile, I have this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y mosquitto
CMD ["mosquitto"]
```

I would expect the mosquitto service to start when I run the image as a container.  I tried the `-d` option with the mosquitto `CMD` command in dockerfile.  However, when I go to `top` or `ps`, I do not see mosquitto as a running process.  When I, from within the container shell, type `mosquitto -d`, and subsequently go to top, I see mosquitto started .  I also trid `systemctl enable mosquitto` followed by `systemctl restart mosquitto`.

Here is my Dockerfile currently:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y mosquitto
CMD ["mosquitto", "-d"]
```

Which I then build the image from this and run it as a container.

I would expect the mosquitto broker to just start when the container does, but it does not.  I am not sure why this is, based on the Docker documentation.

Comment: What command exactly are you running to start the container?  You don’t usually have a “container shell”.

Comment: @DavidMaze I mean that I run this, to get a shell in the container.  ```docker exec -it containername /bin/bash```

Comment: What is your `docker run` command?

Comment: @DavidMaze It is ```docker run -it -p 1883:1883 --name=contname imagename /bin/bash```  The mosquitto command is the in the Dockerfile

Comment: When you put `/bin/bash` in your `docker run` command, that runs _instead of_ the `CMD` in the Dockerfile.  Remove that argument to start the process the image would normally start.

Comment: @DavidMaze  Thank you sir!  I realized I was overlooking that in my attempt to debug code!  Thanks so much!